# LayoutInflater and onFinishInflate()

Tags: android, android-layout

I am running into the `findViewById()` returning NULL problem that a lot of them seem to encounter. I understand that the findViewById() should only be called after the View is inflated in `onFinishInflate()`. My question is - what is view inflation?

In the Activity I call `setContentView(R.layout.testview)` which should call the View constructor and also calls the onDraw(). So that inflates the view does it not? If so why is there a `LayoutInflater` and a function to actually inflate the view? In fact in my code `onInflateView()` is never called even though the whole view is rendered and I was able to interact with the program. That tells me that View inflation is somehow different from calling the View's constructor and `onDraw()` functions. Can someone explain please?

EDIT: Also I have a custom view that I draw using the onDraw() function. Somehow the onFinishInflate() function is never called for me. What can be the reason for this?

-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is - what is view inflation?

View inflation is the act of converting a layout XML file into the corresponding tree of `View` objects. You manually do this using `LayoutInflater`, or Android does it for you from `setContentView()`, built-in `Adapter` classes, etc.

> In the Activity I call setContentView(R.layout.testview) which should call the View constructor and also calls the onDraw(). So that inflates the view does it not?

`setContentView()` inflates the supplied layout file.

> If so why is there a LayoutInflater and a function to actually inflate the view?

Because sometimes you need to do it by hand, such as in a complex `ListView` with different types of rows (e.g.,. header and detail).

Comment: Thanks! Is there an example like that in the Google ApiDemos? Also when is the onFinishInflate() called with setContentView()? In my case its not called at all.

Comment: @user220201: "Is there an example like that in the Google ApiDemos?" -- example of what? "Also when is the onFinishInflate() called with setContentView()? In my case its not called at all." -- I have used `onFinishInflate()` before and it has worked fine, though I don't have any current samples of it. Make sure you have the `@Override` annotation, in case you made a mistake in the method signature.

Comment: I was asking about an example where the LayoutInflater needs to be called.

Comment: @user220201: I have no idea if there is one in ApiDemos. Again, you would use it when you have rows of multiple different types. A `PreferenceActivity` is just a `ListActivity` with lots of different rows. You can see an example of manually invoking `LayoutInflater` here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/FancyLists/DynamicEx  However, this is a simple book example, so it is not showing multiple different rows.